# UWP MVVMCross bind property to method

Tags: mvvm, binding, uwp, cross-platform, mvvmcross

How do I change the content of the second button, based on the method from the first button with MVVPCross?

Something like this:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Button Content="Translate" Click="{x:Bind PhonewordTranslator.Translate}" />
<Button Content="{x:Bind PhonewordTranslatorViewModel.CallButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="{x:Bind PhonewordTranslatorViewModel.Call}" />
```

PhonewordTranslatorViewModel.cs:

```
public class PhonewordTranslatorViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    ...
    private string _callButtonText;
    public string CallButtonText { get=>_callButtonText; set=>SetProperty(ref _callButtonText, value); }

    public void Translate()
    {
        SetProperty(ref _callButtonText, "test123");            
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public void Translate()
{
  CallButtonText = "NewText"; 
  RaisePropertyChanged(() => CallButtonText);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your translate method as below:

```
 public void Translate()
 {
    CallButtonText = "test123";            
 }
```